# Storing query result in a variable with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a query say :

```
"select .... " > $my_result
```

This will store in the `my_result` but as a file. How to store in a `my_result` variable itself if that query gives only one row without creating a file.

Comment: Is this what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash)

Comment: But in this case, if the query gives some error, it will give be null or blank value. How to get 0 in this case

Comment: [bashfaq How can I store the return value and/or output of a command in a variable?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be:

```
my_result=$(select ...)
```

And when you want to print it:

```
echo $my_result
```

Comment: Please do not use backticks, it is [superseded and discouraged](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete). Use `$(...)` for command substitution instead.

Comment: if there is say a connection issue, then it will return say blank, how to handle that case
here `my_result=$(select ...)` 
`my_result1 should be 0 in this case